# Hiding and receiving generic T objects

Tags: generics, rust, dynamic-dispatch

The following Rust code is given:

```
struct Wrapper<T> {
    data: Vec<T>, // more attributes...
}

trait DataWrapper<T> {
    fn get_column(&self) -> &Vec<T>;
    fn get_data(&self, row: usize) -> &T;
}

impl<T> DataWrapper<T> for Wrapper<T> {
    fn get_column(&self) -> &Vec<T> {
        &self.data
    }

    fn get_data(&self, row: usize) -> &T {
        &self.data[row]
    }
}

struct Inter<T> {
    inter_value: Wrapper<T>,
}

trait GetInter {
    fn get_count(&self) -> &str;
}

impl GetInter for Inter<i32> {
    fn get_count(&self) -> &str {
        "i32"
    }
}

impl GetInter for Inter<f64> {
    fn get_count(&self) -> &str {
        "f64"
    }
}

fn create_vector() -> Vec<Box<GetInter>> {
    // Add some sample data
    let x = Wrapper { data: vec![1, 2, 3] };
    let y = Wrapper { data: vec![1.1, 2.2, 3.3] };

    let mut vec: Vec<Box<GetInter>> = Vec::new();

    let m = Inter { inter_value: x };
    let m = Box::new(m);
    let m = m as Box<GetInter>;
    vec.push(m);

    let n = Inter { inter_value: y };
    let n = Box::new(n);
    let n = n as Box<GetInter>;
    vec.push(n);

    vec
}

struct ColumnWrapper {
    columns: Vec<Box<GetInter>>, // more attributes
}

fn create_column_wrapper() -> ColumnWrapper {
    let result = create_vector();

    ColumnWrapper { columns: result }
}

fn main() {
    let result = create_column_wrapper();

    for iter1 in result.columns {
        println!("1: {}", iter1.get_count());
    }
}
```

`Wrapper<T>` stores a generic `Vec`, in detail a data column from an column store. The corresponding implementation returns the `Vec` or a specific element as reference.

The idea of the `Inter<T>` and `GetInter` traits is to hide the generic `T` object, which comes from the Wrapper's `Vec<T>` generic data type. The `get_count()` method is only for test purposes.

`create_vector()` creates two new `Vec`s with some sample data. The result is cast to `GetInter`, wrapped into a `Box` and stored in a `Vec<Box<GetInter>>`. Finally the caller will create a new `ColumnWrapper` element. Now a generic data representation is given.

After compiling and running the correct result is given:

```
i32 
f64
```

Now the real problem starts. I try to access the original data, which are stored in `Wrapper<T>`.

My first idea was to use the dynamic dispatching feature from Rust. It should detect the real data type during runtime.

The `main()` function is modified:

```
fn main() { 
    let result = create_column_wrapper();

    for iter1 in result.columns {
        println!("1: {}", iter1.get_count());

        for iter2 in dyn_dispatch(*iter1) {
            println!("2: {}", iter2);
        }
    }
}
```

The corresponding and not tested `dyn_dispatch()` function:

```
trait Foo<T> {
    fn method(x: &Inter<T>) -> &Vec<T>;
}

impl<i32> Foo<i32> for Inter<i32> {
    fn method(x: &Inter<i32>) -> &Vec<i32> {
        &x.inter_value.data
    }
}

impl<f64> Foo<f64> for Inter<f64> {
    fn method(x: &Inter<f64>) -> &Vec<f64> {
        &x.inter_value.data
    }
}

fn dyn_dispatch<T>(x: &GetInter) -> &Vec<T> {
    Foo::method(&x as &Inter<T>)
}
```

The compilation fails and an error is thrown:

> 85:2 error: conflicting implementations of trait `Foo<_>` for type `Inter<_>`: [E0119]

Any idea how to fix the compilation error or another and *more* easy idea to hide and access the generic `T` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

The first error:

> error: conflicting implementations of trait Foo<*> for type Inter<*>:
>   [E0119]

actually refers to these:

```
impl<i32> Foo<i32> for Inter<i32> { ... }
impl<f64> Foo<f64> for Inter<f64> { ... }
```

Since `i32` and `f64` are parameters, those are both equivalent to:

```
impl<T> Foo<T> for Inter<T> { ... }
```

That is, the implementation of `Foo<T>` for `Inter<T>` *for any T* hence the conflicting implementations.  The fix is to write them as:

```
impl Foo<i32> for Inter<i32> { ... }
```

The next problem is that you're not actually doing dynamic dispatch.  Your `dyn_dispatch` function would have to have `T` specified or inferred at compile time; it can't return a different type each time; similarly you can't just downcast from `GetInter` to `Inter<T>` like that.  You need to do it in the same way as you've done `GetInter::get_count`.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. Adding a function to `GetInter` to return `inter_value` from `Wrapper<T>` requires a generic function or trait. Latter one is not possible. It would break the `ColumnWrapper` idea of un-generic data. Only the generic function remains. How it must be implemented and can you please paste a code snippet to solve the problem?

Comment: If you're hiding behind a generic trait (which is not parameterised), the calling code can't use the actual type - it's not available at compile time anymore.  You could implement a `get_float() -> Option<f64>`, `get_int() -> Option<i32>` etc., which will fail if called on an underlying type which doesn't support it, but if you have something like `fn get<T>() -> T`, every implementer has to work with any type.